# Parallels 9 network establish 2 different network connections

Tags: macos, network, parallels-desktop

I am using Parallels 9 to run Windows on Mac with Mavericks.
and I'd like to connect my Mac and Windows to different networks.

I have connected Windows using ethernet connection but want to connect Mac via WiFi. Can anyone please help me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.

Soln:

1. Open System Preferences, select "Network".
2. Click "Assist Me".
3. In drop down menu, select "Diagnostics".
4. Chose preferred network port configuration.
5. Click "Continue" to finish.